# How to Check if an Index of a Vector of Class Instances is Empty

Tags: c++, vector, indexing

I have a vector of instances of a class called `Node`.  I want to be able to condition on whether or not specific indices of the vector are populated or not.

See the example code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Node {

    int testVal;

public:
    //Default Constructor
    Node() {};
    Node(int a){testVal = a;}

    int getTestVal(){return testVal;}

};


int main(){

    vector<Node> testVector;
    testVector.resize(2);

    Node testNode = Node(5);
    testVector[1] = testNode;

    for (int i = 0;i < 2;i++){

        if (testVector[i] == NULL){
            cout << "Missing Data" << endl;
           }
        else{ 
            cout << testVector[i].getTestVal << endl;
           }     
    }

}
```

The code crashes at the `if` statement.  What is a good way to condition on if a specific index is empty?

Comment: Your code doesn't crash anywhere because it doesn't even compile: `prog.cpp:30:27: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('value_type' (aka 'Node') and 'long')` `prog.cpp:34:35: error: reference to non-static member function must be called; did you mean to call it with no arguments?`

Comment: What do you mean by "is empty"? `testVector[i]` is a `Node`. It can't be anything else.

Comment: Once you declare a vector of `n` Nodes, you have `n` Nodes.  There are no "null" Nodes.  What high-level problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me

Comment: `NULL` sometimes is defined as zero. What you need to do is create a pointer and use new to initialize it (*Node*) with its constructor (Example: `Node * testNode = new Node(5);`) and change all the member call operator "*.*" to "*->*" (Ignore the quotes...) [For example: testVector[i]->getTestVal()]... Also your code is quite not correct because **testVector[0]** is uninitialized...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible.

The vector stores values not pointers, and so you will never get null.

If you want to check for "empty" spots, then declare a vector that stores the address of the nodes:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> testVector;
```

And to store an item in the second index of the vector you do:

```
testVector[1] = std::make_shared<Node>(5);
```

Now the rest of your code should work as expected (just need to fix that call to `getTestVal()` function).

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand C++ semantics.

```
std::vector< Node> testVector; // creates empty vector of Node objects, no Node allocations made here

testVector.resize( 2 ); // calls default constructor and instantiates 2 new Node objects here

// could be done as std::vector< Node > testVector( 2 );
```

That vector has already allocated memory for those 2 Nodes it exists as the default constructor defines the class. It sounds like you want something more like this:

```
...
std::vector< Node * > testVector( 2, null_ptr );
testVector[ 1 ] = new Node( 5 );

for( const auto & ptr : testVector )
    if( ptr )
        std::cout << ptr->getTestVal() << std::endl;

...
delete testVector[ 1 ];
```

As someone else mentioned, smart pointer objects can also be used to manage memory for you and behave similarly.